# Extract key, value from C enumeration using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have several enum from C source code that look like this :

```c
typedef enum
{
    /** comment */
   A    = 1,
    /** comment */
   B    = 2,
}foo_t;

typedef enum
{
    /** comment */
   A    = 1,
    /** comment */
   B    = 2,
}bar_t;
```

I would like to extract lines with key, value pairs which are only related to `foo_t`

Using this regex `(?\w+\s*=\s*\d+,*\s*)+}foo_t` I only extract the line    `B    = 2,` related to `foo_t`. The (A,1) pair is missing.

For the sake of simplification, the example doesn't show that `foo_t` can be located in the middle of a file containing several enum (ie. I need to use `foo_t` identification)

Comment: Note that, by the rules of [tag:regex] tag, you must also tag with the engine, language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one solution is because your regexp is tailored to capture only the second match, by requiring it to be followed by a closing curly. And even if you solve that, no regex engine I know of allows matches to overlap. After you find a match, the search for the next match starts from the end of the previous one. The first match will consume input until `foo_t`; then there are no more matches after it. You need a pattern that will not consume anything past `A = 1`, which means, if you want to do this in one regex search, you need lookahead.

Here's a solution:

```
(?<=\btypedef\s+enum\s*{[^}]*)(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)(?=[^}]*}\s*foo_t\b)
```

However, it only works with regex dialects that permit variable-length lookbehind (The only such engine I know being modern ECMAScript). ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2pZhPV/1)). It also does not work if there are other curly braces inside the typedef, nor if there are equals signs that should not be interpreted as key-value definitions (e.g. inside comments).

If we remove the requirement for the block to start with `typedef`, it is a bit more doable, working in most engines (that have standard regex syntax):

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)(?=[^}]*}\s*foo_t\b)
```

Comment: Conveniently, Python's [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library also supports variable width lookbehinds